# Dynamically created RestController java file with Javassist can be called?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, annotations, javassist

I am experimenting if controller file created by javassist during runtime can be called in postman. Creating a java class with `@RestController` annotation on the class and Postmapping annotation on the method. As expected it was unable to call from postman.

My colleague said it could be because of the annotation scanning timing. When the spring boot is started there is a log like below refresing `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`, so I tried to register the bean to the  `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` but the result was same; not found. 
So wonder if it is even possible in the first place.

```
2019-11-06 15:22:14.825 DEBUG [external-service,,,](20008)[main] [o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext:590] [local] Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@72be135f
2019-11-06 15:22:14.837 DEBUG [external-service,,,](20008)[main] [o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory:213] [local] Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
```

This is the code to create the controller with annotation.

```java
    public Class ctClassController() throws Exception {
        CtClass ctController = this.createCtClass("ctController");
        CtMethod ctMethod = CtNewMethod.make("public String test(){ return 'testController';}", ctController);


        ClassFile cFile = ctController.getClassFile();
        ConstPool constPool = cFile.getConstPool();
        AnnotationsAttribute attr = new AnnotationsAttribute(constPool, AnnotationsAttribute.visibleTag);

        Annotation annotation = new Annotation(RestController.class.getName(), constPool);
        attr.addAnnotation(annotation);

        annotation = new Annotation(Component.class.getName(), constPool);
        attr.addAnnotation(annotation);

        ctController.getClassFile().addAttribute(attr);


        AnnotationsAttribute attr4Method = new AnnotationsAttribute(constPool, AnnotationsAttribute.visibleTag);
        annotation = new Annotation(PostMapping.class.getName(), constPool);
        annotation.addMemberValue("value", new StringMemberValue("/api/ctController", constPool));
        attr4Method.setAnnotation(annotation);


        ctMethod.getMethodInfo().addAttribute(attr4Method);
        ctController.addMethod(ctMethod);

         ctController.toClass(this.getClass().getClassLoader(), this.getClass().getProtectionDomain());
        Class klass = Class.forName("ctController");

        return klass;

    }
```

and the following was the trial to rescan the annotation.

```java
Class controllerKlass = vendorDynamicClassConstructor.ctClassController();
Object controllerObj = controllerKlass.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();

 AbstractApplicationContext abstractContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();

    abstractContext.refresh();

        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
context.register(controllerObj.getClass());
        context.refresh();
```

so if i call from postman like this,  http://localhost:2028/api/ctController
i want to see the 'testController' however i get the following. Would there be another way ?

```
<Map>
    <timestamp>1573026801879</timestamp>
    <status>404</status>
    <error>Not Found</error>
    <message>No message available</message>
    <path>/api/ctController</path>
</Map>
```

Comment: Ofcourse this won't work. You are registereing it with an arbitrary `ApplicationContext` not connected to the one used by Spring Boot`. So no this won't work. You will need to place this in the `main` method and register/add the bean there to the context **before** you call the `run` method. Or place that code in an `@Configuration` class which has an `@Bean` method which does this.